# Laravel (Mandrill/Ajax) email sending on dev not production

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've spent all night trying different things and for the life of me I cannot get my site to send emails. I just deployed my first Laravel project to a live server (digitalocean), yet when on my vagrant dev machine I have no problems sending email, it isn't until I deploy that the problems began.

I know the 500 error is usually due to the CSRF tokens and passing them in your headers, but I am doing that and am still getting an error. I will post the code I assume would be relevant and if anyone can see what the hell I am doing wrong I will forever be in your debt.

MAIL: (Asterix for privacy)

```
return [
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => array('address' => '********@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Admin'),
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => '********@gmail.com',
    'password' => '****************',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
];
```

HomeController @store method for email sending (works on dev)

```
public function store(ContactFormRequest $request)
{
    Mail::send('emails.email', array(
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'user_message' => $request->get('user_message')
        ), function($message)
    {
        $message->from('*********@gmail.com');
        $message->to('********@gmail.com', 'Admin')->subject('Client Inquiry');
    });

    return Response::json(['response' => 200]);
}
```

AJAX (jQuery)

```
$('#submit-contact-form').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#submit-contact-form').val('Sending...');
    var $form = $(this).parent('form');
    var $action = $form.attr('action');
    var $data = $form.serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: $action,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') },
    data: $data,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.response == 200) {
            $('#submit-contact-form').val('Thank You For Contacting Us!');
        }
    }
});
```

});

Routes.php: (contact form is on my homepage and posts to itself, works on dev)

```
Route::resource('/', 'HomeController', ['only' => ['index','store']]);
```

Finally Form: (discovered if posting to root, for the url you have to pass empty string with a space in it

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => ' ', 'id' => 'contact-form')) !!}
    blah blah blah
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I am new to Laravel so i'm still learning, but this one has me stuck especially because it works on dev and not production.

Here is my error log:

```
[2015-05-14 06:29:01] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), called in /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php on line 11268 and defined' in /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php:11262
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(11262): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Missing argumen...', '/var/www/html/k...', 11262, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(11268): Illuminate\Support\Manager->createDriver()
#2 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(11258): Illuminate\Support\Manager->createDriver(NULL)
#3 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.php(92): Illuminate\Support\Manager->driver()
#4 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(827): Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider->Illuminate\Mail\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#5 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(1027): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#6 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(980): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#7 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(1493): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('swift.mailer', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(1213): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('swift.mailer')
#9 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.php(30): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('swift.mailer')
#10 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(1027): Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider->Illuminate\Mail\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#11 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(980): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#12 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(1493): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('mailer', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(1213): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('mailer')
#14 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(5276): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('mailer')
#15 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(5262): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::resolveFacadeInstance('mailer')
#16 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(5296): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::getFacadeRoot()
#17 /var/www/html/kraken/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php(28): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('send', Array)
#18 /var/www/html/kraken/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php(28): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('emails.email', Array, Object(Closure))
#19 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\HomeController->store(Object(App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest))
#20 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8287): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8354): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('store', Array)
#22 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8333): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\HomeController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'store')
#23 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8952): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8935): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8334): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#28 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8320): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\HomeController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'store')
#29 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(7317): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\Http\Contro...', 'store')
#30 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(7288): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(6954): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8952): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8935): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(6955): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#37 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(6944): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(6929): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(1935): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8952): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(2438): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /var/www/html/kraken/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8944): App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(12083): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8944): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(10785): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8944): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#49 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(11789): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8944): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(11738): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8944): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#53 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(2478): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8944): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#55 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(8935): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#57 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(1891): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#58 /var/www/html/kraken/vendor/compiled.php(1880): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 /var/www/html/kraken/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 {main}
```

I've already gone to Laracast and posted but didn't get any responses, if anyone can help me I would appreciate it so much, thanks guys.

Comment: did you try `php artisan clear-compiled` on prod server?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I was getting worried because I had no responses between this and the larscasts forum lol so I really apreciate you taking the time. I tried the clear compiled and no luck still. I think its my server settings as my dev environment was setup with vagrant and PUPHPet so it was all preconfigured whereas my digitalocean is just an empty LAMP server. Still not sure how to fix it but will keep hacking away since the code works on dev but not prod the only thing i can think of is my apache settings.